# Проблема CollapsingToolbarLayout при использовании опции adjustResize

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Есть следующая разметка, привожу только нужные части:

```
<CoordinatorLayout
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...>
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        ...
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            .../>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_send"
                .../>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    ...
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            .../>
        ......
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

При нажатии на текстовое поле, я програмно сворачиваю AppBarLayout что бы было место написать описание, и все хорошо сжимается как надо.
Но вот как начинаешь печать текст в поле, то начинают вылазить подсказки (от клавиатуры) и всвязи с этим происходит уменьшение окна, да и при том некорректно, уменьшается AppBarLayout вместо NestedScrollView, и Toolbar вообще вверх уходит.
Вообщем все на скринах видно:

http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/5/2/Screenshot_3341743_20461752.png

http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/8/2/Screenshot_7057356_20461782.png

http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/9/1/Screenshot_7970157_20461791.png

Версия - android.support:design:23.1.0

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Дело было в том что AppBarLayout нужно было задать фиксированную высоту, а у меня там стояло wrap_content.

Comment: эм, и как он сворачиваться/разворачиваться будет при фиксированной высоте?

Comment: Обычно AppBarLayout и задают высоту, но вряд ли это будет фиксированная высота, скорее начальная, так как потом он ее так же сворачивает/разворачивает но уже без того бага с подсказками при вводе.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже что `NestedScrollView` достигает своей минимальной высоты и дальше уменьшаться не намерен, надо бы определить что ему эту минимальную высоту определяет. Возможно этот глюк из за атрибута `android:fillViewport="true"` который тут явно не нужен, ибо у вложенного `LinearLayout` высота `wrap_content` а не `match_parent`. Попробуйте ещё задать для `CollapsingToolbarLayout` или `AppBarLayout` минимальную высоту `android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: Нет `fillViewport` там нужен что бы EditText максимально расширить, но я сейчас вот и указан минимальную высоту, и убирал `fillViewport` баг остается, похоже тут дело именно в CollapsingToolbarLayout и adjustResize